# Centering captions under figures

Tags: horizontal-alignment, captions

Is there a way to do this? All mine are left aligned; however, I want them centered. How is it done?

Also related: how do I embolden all of my captions?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,fleqn,titlepage]{report}
\usepackage[margin=2.0cm]{geometry}                % See geometry.pdf to learn the layout options. There are lots.
\geometry{letterpaper}                   % ... or a4paper or a5paper or ... 
%\geometry{landscape}                % Activate for for rotated page geometry
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}    % Activate to begin paragraphs with an empty line rather than an indent
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\newcommand{\sectionbreak}{\clearpage}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-30pt}{12pt}
\DeclareGraphicsRule{.tif}{png}{.png}{`convert #1 `dirname #1`/`basename #1 .tif`.png}
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\arabic{footnote}}
\usepackage[perpage,bottom]{footmisc}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
\captionsetup{width=13cm}
\caption{Load of stuff above the table which is wider than the table, can use width to limit that as above but want it centralised, also might be numbers in here which means when I want to embolden the entire caption from the preamle so that it does it for all figures in my document that the numbers like this $n=1,2,3,4,5,6$ and $7$ will embolden too. If I put this in at the moment it looks like my actual text and so there is lttle way to discern between the two.}
\vspace{0.3cm}
\begin{tabular}{| l | l | l |}
\hline
Thing1 & Thing2 & Thing3 \\ \hline
blah1 & blah2 & blah3 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\label{table:stuff}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Please excuse the preamble as I don't really know what relates to what, I just know that these have been collected over time to be able to write my entire document so all are used at some point. I you want I can edit them out...

So I want a way to embolden, centralise and change font size of all my captions globally, and by centralise I mean center align, so they are not left aligned.

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @egreg Question edited, if this isn't what you wanted comment and I can edit the question appropriately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need for an extra package; since you are loading `caption`, you can use its features:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,fleqn,titlepage]{report}
\usepackage{caption}

\captionsetup{width=.75\textwidth,font={bf,scriptsize},skip=0.3cm,within=none}


\begin{document}

\chapter{Test}
\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{Load of stuff above the table which is wider than the table, can use width to limit that as above but want it centralised, also might be numbers in here which means when I want to embolden the entire caption from the preamle so that it does it for all figures in my document that the numbers like this $n=1,2,3,4,5,6$ and $7$ will embolden too. If I put this in at the moment it looks like my actual text and so there is lttle way to discern between the two.}
\begin{tabular}{| l | l | l |}
\hline
Thing1 & Thing2 & Thing3 \\ \hline
blah1 & blah2 & blah3 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\label{table:stuff}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect, they do the same thing, but this is a neater answer. Thanks.

Comment: This can be minimized by using `\captionsetup{within=none}`, no need for the `chngcntr` package.

Comment: @AxelSommerfeldt I incorporated your suggestion into my answer, Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Is this closer to what you are looking for?  The first table is what you had.  The second is using `boxhandler`.  The caption width, fontsize of the caption and the boldness of normal text in the caption have all been changed in the preamble and will apply to all tables and figures.  The bold math in the caption can not be globally changed in the table captions without also changing it in the rest of your document.  Thus, the `\mathbf` is part of each figure caption using math.  The parameters I used are caption width=`.5\textwidth` and the caption is in scriptsize bold.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,fleqn,titlepage]{report}
\usepackage[margin=2.0cm]{geometry}                % See geometry.pdf to learn the layout options. There are lots.
\geometry{letterpaper}                   % ... or a4paper or a5paper or ... 
%\geometry{landscape}                % Activate for for rotated page geometry
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}    % Activate to begin paragraphs with an empty line rather than an indent
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{titlesec}
%
\usepackage{boxhandler}
\captionStyle{n}{c}
\constrainCaptionWidth{.5\textwidth}
\def\CaptionFontSize{\scriptsize\bfseries}
%
\newcommand{\sectionbreak}{\clearpage}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-30pt}{12pt}
\DeclareGraphicsRule{.tif}{png}{.png}{`convert #1 `dirname #1`/`basename #1 .tif`.png}
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\arabic{footnote}}
\usepackage[perpage,bottom]{footmisc}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
\captionsetup{width=13cm}
\caption{Load of stuff above the table which is wider than the table, can use width to limit that as above but want it centralised, also might be numbers in here which means when I want to embolden the entire caption from the preamle so that it does it for all figures in my document that the numbers like this $n=1,2,3,4,5,6$ and $7$ will embolden too. If I put this in at the moment it looks like my actual text and so there is lttle way to discern between the two.}
\vspace{0.3cm}
\begin{tabular}{| l | l | l |}
\hline
Thing1 & Thing2 & Thing3 \\ \hline
blah1 & blah2 & blah3 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\label{table:stuff}
\end{table}

\bxtable[ht]
{Load of stuff above the table which is wider than the table,
can use width to limit that as above but want it centralised, also might
be numbers in here which means when I want to embolden the entire
caption from the preamle so that it does it for all figures in my
document that the numbers like this $\mathbf{n=1,2,3,4,5,6}$ and
$\mathbf{7}$ will
embolden too. If I put this in at the moment it looks like my actual
text and so there is lttle way to discern between the two}
{
\begin{tabular}{| l | l | l |}
\hline
Thing1 & Thing2 & Thing3 \\ \hline
blah1 & blah2 & blah3 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect! Thanks, have deleted the comment as now inappropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Use `\makebox[\textwidth]{}`

```
\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
\makebox[\textwidth]{
\captionsetup{width=13cm}
\caption{Load of stuff above the table which is wider than the table, can use width to limit that as above but want it centralised, also might be numbers in here which means when I want to embolden the entire caption from the preamle so that it does it for all figures in my document that the numbers like this $n=1,2,3,4,5,6$ and $7$ will embolden too. If I put this in at the moment it looks like my actual text and so there is lttle way to discern between the two.}
\vspace{0.3cm}
\begin{tabular}{| l | l | l |}
\hline
Thing1 & Thing2 & Thing3 \\ \hline
blah1 & blah2 & blah3 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}}
\label{table:stuff}
\end{table}
```